# How do I get rid of changing page with trackpad in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I keep accidentally going back to the previous page on Firefox by moving over the trackpad. I've tried to find it on Google.

What is the configuration change I need to make to get rid of that feature? I'm talking about the feature that causes you to change pages in Firefox by moving with two fingers on the trackpad.

Comment: Does this happen in IE or Chrome? If so, it's a gesture set by the trackpad driver. If it doesn't, then we can search for a possible about:config option to change it.

Answer (score 0):

If you dive into `about:config` and search for 'gesture.swipe' you'll find a few strings that determine what each action does. According to what I've read, if you set these to empty strings, it will remove the associated action. See also [this Mozilla Support question](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1003526).

[image: Screenshot of about:config]